# Run GcmListenerService New Process

Tags: android, xamarin.android

To start i'm not a very skilled in android programming, so be patient.

So, i'm creating an application that send and receive messages to my *GCM* server using [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/) tutorial. 
When i was testing with the basic, sending and receiving basic messages, worked great.

Now i'm trying to implement to more complex methods, and one of then is a syncronized method.

The problem: i've discovered that, if my *UIThread* hangs for a while, the service that receives the *GCM* messages hang too. Looks like they are running in that same process.

Is possible to separate the two process ? Keeps *GCM* running in one, while the UI runs in another ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All GcmListenerService methods are invoked asynchronously (except your methods). There are no other processes, but threads. Use your own  [thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html?hl=ru)

Comment: That's the point, if the UIThread hangs, the GCM service hangs too. For example, if i put _while(true)_ in _UIThread_, then use my GCM server to send a message to the device, it won't receive (call method _OnMessageReceived_) until i unblock the _UIThread_.